# Roll bone hotkey?

Tags: armature, transforms, bones

Is there a hotkey to roll a bone in edit mode?  Rotating (with <kbd>R</kbd>) along the normal-space y-axis does nothing.

[image]
I am looking for a hotkey to adjust this value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, in the standard keymap, rolls the selected bone(s).